When you have a mat-form-field with a button in it, in a form, when you press enter it auto focus to that input. This is not desired
In Angular 17, if you have a mat-form-field with a button in it, like the below, then when you press enter on any other form input in the form, like a checkbox, radio-button it automatically places focus on the input with the button. This is odd, no? I think it's a bug.
    <form [formGroup]="reactiveForm"  >

        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select a fruit" formControlName="radioFruit">
          <mat-radio-button aria-label="apples" value="apples">Apples</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button aria-label="oranges" value="oranges">Oranges</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text">
          <button mat-icon-button matSuffix >
            <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-form-field>

    </form>



Hey mate, I copied your exact code and it still happens. So maybe it's an Angular 17 bug and they fixed it in 19, which is what your stackblitz is?

For others, this is very much reproducible. It can't be the desired behavior. Imagine you have a long form, someone hits the Enter button and it shoots down to the input with the button and executes the buttons method. That is an accessibility problem.

I forgot to delete my comment after I reproduced, updated my answer!

If you want to get rid of this behaviour you can use $event.stopPropogation() to stop the autoselection.
To stop the button from being selected by enter key you should set the type of the button as type="button".
<button
  mat-icon-button
  matSuffix
  (click)="hide = !hide"
  tabindex="-1"
  type="button"
>
  <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
</button>

Stackblitz Demo

Since you are having the button inside the form field, you are getting this auto focus, this is expected behaviour.
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
  <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select a fruit" formControlName="radioFruit">
    <mat-radio-button aria-label="apples" value="apples"
      >Apples</mat-radio-button
    >
    <mat-radio-button aria-label="oranges" value="oranges"
      >Oranges</mat-radio-button
    >
  </mat-radio-group>
  <br />
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [type]="hide ? 'text' : 'password'"
      formControlName="password"
    />
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">
      <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Stackblitz Demo


well, the stopProgogation does stop the focus from moving, but the hide toggle still happens. This can't be desired behavior from Angular. It's too disruptive.

@Mark updated my answer, we should adjust the button to get rid of this selection behaviour
